# want to join multiple tables with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, jdbc, inner-join

Below is my query

```
SELECT salary.id,
       employee.emp_id,
       employee.emp_name,
       department.dept_name,
       designation.desig_name,
       salary.basic,
       salary.house_rent + salary.conveyance + salary.medical + salary.dearness + salary.others_allowances AS allowances,
       salary.income_tax + salary.pro_tax + salary.emp_state_insu + salary.others_deductions AS deductions,
       Sum(attendance.attendance = 'Absent') * salary.absence_fine AS fine,
       Monthname(attendance.date) AS month,
       salary.month AS monYear
  FROM employee
       INNER JOIN attendance ON employee.emp_id = attendance.emp_id
       INNER JOIN department ON employee.dept_id = department.dept_id
       INNER JOIN designation ON employee.desig_id = designation.desig_id
       INNER JOIN salary ON designation.desig_id = salary.desig_id
  GROUP BY salary.id,
           employee.emp_id,
           Monthname(attendance.date)
```

My output is:

[image: image link]

Please help me to figure out this problem

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the problem as I don't believe it's clear from the image you used

Comment: Did you noticed that you are using two diferent columns to see the mont.
attendance.date to monthname function and salary.month to month/year. So you got 2 situations: 
1 - The columns are storing different dates
2 - You got a problem with your joins

Comment: Incompletely specified aggregating/GROUP queries give non-deterministic (semi-random) results in fields that were neither grouped by nor aggregated.

Comment: month column se from attendance table and yearMonth from salary table .. my query produce output by deducting fine from all records of salary even they are from different months ... it should deduct december deuction fine from monthYear value Dec 2018 ..but it deducting from all even from oct 2018 etc

Comment: how can I improve my query or table relations suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a column to relate attendance with salary lets say that you have a column called month_id on each table, then u can add a condition in the last inner join. 
something like this:

```
INNER JOIN salary ON designation.desig_id = salary.desig_id and attendace.monthId = salary.month_id
```